# Honda Civic 2012 the car wouldnot open with clicker or with master key

Tags: battery, door, alarm

After coming from vacation (11 days) my Honda would not open with key had to call CAA they open the door and gave a boost 
I am driving but the alarm light does not flush 
what my next step should be

Comment: It sounds like there is a significant draw on the battery or you have a very weak battery (enough to start, but not enough to sustain it without starting it every day). I'm not totally sure what your question is, though. Next step for what? Does the fob still not open the doors when used? Which security light are you talking about? Some have a small LED which blinks ... Is this not blinking? Please help us out here.